# In-built Shell cmd to obtain network traffic

Tags: shell, unix, networking

Is there an in-built shell command that can be used to obtain network traffic in units like KBps (like 'ifstat' does)?
The script needs to be deployed on several servers. So I want to avoid having to install utilities on the server. Hence , I am looking for a shell command available on all unix systems that does not need to be explicitly installed.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not really looking for an "in-built shell command" because a shell (like `sh` or `bash`) does not typically have *any* built-in commands for dealling with networking.  Commands like `ifconfig` or `ifstat` are separate from the shell, and may or may not be available depending on the environment.

You will probably find the `netstat` command installed in most places (but not all, because some distributions are replacing `netstat` with `ss`).  The `netstat -i` command will give you interface statistics:

```
$ netstat -i
Iface      MTU    RX-OK RX-ERR RX-DRP RX-OVR    TX-OK TX-ERR TX-DRP TX-OVR Flg
br-int    1500       52      0     15 0             8      0      0      0 BMRU
eth0      1500   654193      0      3 0        606053      0      0      0 BMRU
lo       65536   109083      0      0 0        109083      0      0      0 LRU
qbr9f79e  1500        7      0      0 0             8      0      0      0 BMRU
qvb9f79e  1500        9      0      0 0            15      0      0      0 BMPRU
qvo9f79e  1500       15      0      0 0             9      0      0      0 BMPRU
```

The `RX-OK` and `TX-OK` columns are the number of bytes transferred in each direction.